# How do I add an Google Ads in my flutter desktop aplication?

Tags: flutter, google-ads-api

I'm looking for a way to put Google ads in my desktop program.
I don't know if is not released yet. But I could find only for android and IOS.

Comment: There is currently no ad support for the platforms: MacOS, Linux and Windows.
For more information visit: https://pub.dev/